# How to call a delegate function from web3js

Tags: solidity, web3js

I am trying to call a delegate function from web3 but, everytime its saying its not

```
var myContract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi,add);
myContract.methods.enterMarkets(['cadd']).send({from:ethereum.selectedAddress});
```

error

```
Uncaught TypeError: myContract.methods.enterMarkets is not a function at <anonymous>:1:16
```

`0xe7bc397DBd069fC7d0109C0636d06888bb50668c` this is the smart contract on kovan

can you please explain how to call a delegateFunction from web3? with example would be great.

edit

smart contract 1 `0xe7bc397DBd069fC7d0109C0636d06888bb50668c` [here](https://kovan.etherscan.io/address/0xe7bc397DBd069fC7d0109C0636d06888bb50668c#code)

```
interface ComptrollerInterface {
/**
 * @notice Marker function used for light validation when updating the comptroller of a market
 * @dev Implementations should simply return true.
 * @return true
 */

/*** Assets You Are In ***/

function enterMarkets(address[] calldata cTokens) external returns (uint[] memory);
function exitMarket(address cToken) external returns (uint);

}
```

smart contract 2 `0x1f5D7F3CaAC149fE41b8bd62A3673FE6eC0AB73b` [here](https://kovan.etherscan.io/address/0x1f5d7f3caac149fe41b8bd62a3673fe6ec0ab73b#readContract)

smart contract 3 `0x3Afec0b1Ec510E59A757133059039828640839c7` [enter link description here](http://0x3Afec0b1Ec510E59A757133059039828640839c7)

```
contract Comptroller is ComptrollerV2Storage, ComptrollerInterface, ComptrollerErrorReporter, Exponential {
/**
 * @notice Add assets to be included in account liquidity calculation
 * @param cTokens The list of addresses of the cToken markets to be enabled
 * @return Success indicator for whether each corresponding market was entered
 */
function enterMarkets(address[] memory cTokens) public returns (uint[] memory) {
    uint len = cTokens.length;

    uint[] memory results = new uint[](len);
    for (uint i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        CToken cToken = CToken(cTokens[i]);

        results[i] = uint(addToMarketInternal(cToken, msg.sender));
    }

    return results;
}
}
```

sorry these are not my contracts, its from compound.finance on kovan Testnet
but, most importantly how do we call delegateFunction from web3js?

this is the [transaction](https://kovan.etherscan.io/tx/0x15faf4b7331b4e3ed72e6e32419b158ac6b67f25ec779286fe2a831ffa73fe55) working.

and i am trying to call the same on the same contract that is mentioned in the transaction but same error.

Comment: Can you please share the relevant part of your contract's code?

Comment: The error indicates that `enterMarkets` is not exposed in `abi`, which AFAIK, can be the result of only one thing - no external or public function named `enterMarkets` in your contract or in any contract up the inheritance line of your contract.

Comment: @goodvibration i have updated the code and the smart contracts detail

Comment: Like I said, your `abi` array probably does not include function `enterMarkets`. Please verify this (for example, with `console.log(abi)`). You might wanna make sure that you take the correct one, after compiling your contract.

Comment: @goodvibration yes thats true my `abi` does not have the `enterMarkets` function but then this transaction https://kovan.etherscan.io/tx/0x15faf4b7331b4e3ed72e6e32419b158ac6b67f25ec779286fe2a831ffa73fe55 is working in same sense

Comment: What does this transaction (or any other transaction for that matter) have to do with the local variable `abi` that you declare and initialize in your script??? If this variable (array) doesn't have `func` in it, then you will not be able to call `contract.methods.func`! It's like trying to access `x.y` when `x` has no property `y`.

Answer (score 0):

With `myContract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi)`, the one and only reason for:

```
Uncaught TypeError: myContract.methods.enterMarkets is not a function
```

Is if `abi` is an array which does not include the following element:

```
{
    "constant"        : <true> or <false>,
    "inputs"          : [...],
    "name"            : "enterMarkets",
    "outputs"         : [...],
    "payable"         : <true> or <false>,
    "stateMutability" : <"pure"> or <"view"> or <"payable"> or <"nonpayable">,
    "type"            : "function"
}
```

There is absolutely no transaction or web3 call involved here, because your attempt to execute `myContract.methods.enterMarkets` fails before any RPC is even sent to the node. It's like trying to access `x.y`, where `x` is an object which doesn't have property `y`.

So you should inspect the local variable `abi` and figure out why it doesn't include that element. For example, perhaps it's the output of an old compilation, before you've added that function to the contract, or perhaps it's the output of the compilation of a totally different contract...